# How to find which software is over using the CPU in windows?

Tags: windows, cpu

My problem is the overusage of CPU in windows 7. The performance tab in task manager shows a very high usage level, usually more than 50% usage. But in the processes tab it shows an ordinary situation and just some processes with 2 or 3 percent of usage. Also the system is not working in a light way. Is it a hidden software? and how can I solve this problem?

#### Screenshot of CPU usage:

[image]

#### Screenshot of processes sorted by CPU usage:

[image]

Comment: In your screen shot you don't have "Show processes from all users" checked, check that one. I bet some system process is running and eating the CPU up.

Comment: thanks alot Matthew ... I checked it and found it .... syshost.exe is eating the cpu ... I will search about this file ...

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete don't use comments for answer please, comments can't be accepted.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík It is not an answer. As we still can't tell him what is eating the CPU and how to solve it until he does the show process form all users.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete you're right, but I think once he does list all processes it will be pretty straightforward. Also your comment answers the question in the title, i.e. *How to...* and not *What is eating my cpu...*.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your comment that you did the `Show processes from all users` and found that `syshost.exe` is eating your CPU I did a quick look and most of the results point to a **Trojan** on the system. I would recommend getting a good virus scan done to remove it.